# Can I use PS2-to-WII adapters for Guitar Hero, Rock Band, Dance Dance Revolution?

Tags: nintendo-wii, ps2, rock-band, guitar-hero, dance-dance-revolution

I just got a Nintendo Wii, and I don't want to have to purchase new instances of all my varied PS2 controllers.

I've got Guitar Hero guitars.
I've got Rock Band drums.
I've got Dance Dance Revolution dancepads.  Like... 6 of them!

...I don't want to have to start over.

Can I buy a PS2-to-Wii adapter and simply start playing Guitar Hero on the Wii, with the same hardware?

That would be best.

Comment: Probably not, there's a few different ways a PS2 to Wii adapter can be made, and none of them are likely to convert all of these specialized controller's inputs from what the PS2 game expects to what Wii game expects. Unless one or more of your controllers use USB you're probably not going to have any luck with any of them.

Comment: Hmm... I'd settle for something over nothing. Is there a game compatibility chart somewhere? Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some quick research I have determined that you should be able to do this. If your guitar is wired, try out [this adapter](http://www.dx.com/p/playstation-2-ps2-to-wii-controller-adapter-13-5cm-cable-23206#.VOOnpfnF9Ao).

Someone on [this thread](http://www.scorehero.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1718726&sid=59d4da0ae325859ac5308cba709c9d2b#1718726) has confirmed that it did in fact work for them using a PS2/PS3 Peak Starpex Guitar.

If whatever reason the thread link breaks down, here's what was said:

```
Hey y'all! 

I bought this puppy based on the reviews I mentioned above,
and it works perfectly with my PS2/PS3 Peak Starpex guitar. 

This thing is awesome!!! 

(p.s. despite the timing of my post, this is not an april's fool crack)
```

and here is an image of the product:

`Playstation 2 PS2 to Wii Controller Adapter (13.5CM-Cable)`

[image: PS2-Wii Converter]

Comment: Thanks. I looked up the link to buy this, and am putting it here in case the original forum disappears:

http://www.dx.com/p/playstation-2-ps2-to-wii-controller-adapter-13-5cm-cable-23206